# how to make procedure insert

Tags: sql-server

Please help, how to correct this procedure??

Right now, I'm getting an error:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_FILEUPLOAD
            @UID int,
            @APPCODE varchar(50) = NULL ,
            @APPEXPIRED datetime = NULL  ,
            @SIGNIMAGE image = NULL ,
            @SIGNFILE varbinary(MAX) = NULL ,
            @HEADUID int,
            @PRINCIPALFROM money,
            @PRINCIPALTO money,
            @EXCEPTIONUSER bit,
            @LastUpdate datetime
    AS 
        BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO APPUSERDTL
            (UID,
            APPCODE,
            APPEXPIRED,
            SIGNIMAGE, 
            SIGNFILE,
            HEADUID,
            PRINCIPALFROM,
            PRINCIPALTO,
            EXCEPTIONUSER,
            LastUpdate)
VALUES('@UID',
            '@APPCODE',
            '@APPEXPIRED',
            '@SIGNIMAGE',
            '@SIGNFILE',
            '@HEADUID',
            '@PRINCIPALFROM',
            '@PRINCIPALTO',
            '@EXCEPTIONUSER',
            '@LastUpdate')

    END 
    GO
```

Below is the table structure

```
[dbo].[APPUSERDTL]( 
      [UID] [int] NOT NULL, 
      [APPCODE] [varchar](50) NULL, 
      [APPEXPIRED] [datetime] NULL, 
      [SIGNIMAGE] [image] NULL, 
      [SIGNFILE] [varbinary](max) NULL, 
      [HEADUID] [int] NULL, 
      [PRINCIPALFROM] [money] NOT NULL, 
      [PRINCIPALTO] [money] NOT NULL, 
      [EXCEPTIONUSER] [bit] NOT NULL, 
     [LastUpdate] [datetime] NOT NULL )
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the column SIGNFILE in your DB table?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the SQL Server trying to perform conversion from the empty string (`''`) to the `varbinary(max)` the error occurred. The only way to do is to avoid implicit conversion. If you need to convert the empty string to varbinary type, use the `cast(@your_variable as varbinary(max))` construction (in the above code where you calling to you SP `SP_FILEUPLOAD` from).

Comment: This will not work. try `declare @test varbinary(max)=''
select cast(@test as varbinary(max))` You can't `cast/convert` empty string to `varbinary` !!!

Comment: Sure. But if you will wrote this in another manner as `declare @x varchar(max) = '', @test varbinary(max); select @test = cast(@x as varbinary(max))` this will work fine and this was the answer...

Comment: The issue in this question was the OP was passing all the parameters to insert statement within `''` which lead to consider all as `varchar` !!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are passing a `varchar` value to   `@SIGNFILE` parameter.

Please check the value you are passing

eg. You can replicate this issue

```
declare @test varbinary(max)=''
select @test
```

***Update***

Why you are passing with `''` to insert statement? It will consider all the values as `varchar` if you use within quotes. Remove quotes and try

You can do as below

```
INSERT INTO APPUSERDTL
            (UID,
            APPCODE,
            APPEXPIRED,
            SIGNIMAGE, 
            SIGNFILE,
            HEADUID,
            PRINCIPALFROM,
            PRINCIPALTO,
            EXCEPTIONUSER,
            LastUpdate)
     VALUES(@UID,
            @APPCODE,
            @APPEXPIRED,
            @SIGNIMAGE,
            @SIGNFILE,
            @HEADUID,
            @PRINCIPALFROM,
            @PRINCIPALTO,
            @EXCEPTIONUSER,
            @LastUpdate)
```

Comment: Where are you calling the stored procedure? can you please update your question with that? Also the table definition will be helpful to find the issue!

Comment: this table schema.......[dbo].[APPUSERDTL](
 [UID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [APPCODE] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [APPEXPIRED] [datetime] NULL,
 [SIGNIMAGE] [image] NULL,
 [SIGNFILE] [varbinary](max) NULL,
 [HEADUID] [int] NULL,
 [PRINCIPALFROM] [money] NOT NULL,
 [PRINCIPALTO] [money] NOT NULL,
 [EXCEPTIONUSER] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [LastUpdate] [datetime] NOT NULL

Comment: how to create procedure insert?plis i'm newbie

Comment: @arifpratama: Just remove `''` in values and just pass the parameters

Comment: implicit convert of empty string to varbinary will fail.

Comment: @Sandr: yes, that what I have mentioned!